# Windows 2000 disk image: was ACPI enabled?

Tags: windows, bios, bsod, acpi, windows-2000

I have an old (2005) industrial PC running Windows 2000. It operates a CNC machine, so almost every bit of it is proprietary, except Windows and basic hardware standards (ISA bus etc).

All of a sudden it stopped booting at all (no POST, just blank screen). No recent hardware changes took place, I've nothing to blame at all. I've recorded POST sequence: d0, 00, d1, d2. Resembles AMIBIOS8 (except 00h code), but it's not (I've dumped flash chip with parallel programmer to check for data consistency and BIOS manufacturer) - it's completely custom.

There's no info on original mobo (SECO M671 - an obscure old ETX-formfactor module, very similar to Kontron pm-15c, but from a different vendor, i.e. same chips, but in a different PCB arrangement). But, I've found similar ETX module mobo (Kontron pm-10c - processor has different frequency, but is still the same family, other chips are identical) still available from a local dealer, replaced the mobo and PC POSTed successfully.

But here is the problem: new mobo's bios has plenty of settings the old one missed. One of such settings (apart from memory caching and other features I've disabled as a precaution) is "Enable ACPI", but at this point I only have a disk image of the OS installation. How do I find out whether or not this installation used ACPI? On a running system HKLM/HARDWARE hive has some clues, but it's volatile. I wonder, if registry contains some non-volatile ACPI-related settings?

P.S. I've already tried to guess, but failed. Windows booted successfully, but shortly after after started fail with 0x7F = unexpected kernel-mode trap (0x08 = double fault) BSOD. WinDbg says it's probably memory_corrption by a DRIVER_FAULT, but it does not name the driver. Every time I boot the system, BSOD probability rises: at first it only happened when I tried to launch some proprietary software, now it sometimes happens even before logon. Now I've to find out if it's worth to try another ACPI option, or the new mobo is somehow (BIOS resources arrangement?) incompatible with proprietary OEM software and therefore all hope is lost.

Comment: First of all.. FUN PROBLEM! :)  -- Are you sure those errors are related to ACPI?  Have you already tried dropping a NEW DRIVE with a NEW OS in it to make sure everything else is working first?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I would've reinstalled the OS if I had all the installers for proprietary CNC software. Unfortunately, this is not the case. I could try to move software manually without installers, but who knows what problems it'll bring up. So I'm trying to make existing OS image work on new hardware. Well, I figured that the drivers worked on the previous mobo that differs only by CPU model (Celeron M 1GHz vs 1.5GHz) and BIOS. Don't think that CPU frequency (architecture is the same) is the culprit, therefore BIOS settings are left (at least worth a try).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some deeper googling revealed that there are multiple ways to do that:

1. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ApmLegalHal - this is APM HAL presence marker, as indicated in the corresponding section of WINNT\inf\hal.inf (also this inf suggests that the marker is cleared before new HAL is installed).
   Note that on a non-running machine there is no CurrentControlSet, because this is just a link to ControlSet001 or 002 (the exact set number is stored in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\Select - "Current" DWORD).
2. Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services there are ACPI services, which are set (this is my speculation) to Start = 0x04 = Disabled if the machine uses APM.
3. WINNT\setup.inf lists original filename for hal.dll. My system appears to be using APM and therefore original name coincides with hal.dll. But for ACPI systems it's "halacpi" or similar ("halmacpi" and so on). Original filename is also listed in file properties.